# Integrate IBM Connections Activity Stream into a web page

Tags: android-activity, ibm-connections

I am wondering if there is a way to have/ to integrate/ to add the IBM Connections activity streams into a web page.
So that my web page will display the activity streams.
The activity stream would be inserted / integrated in my web page and it will be updated accordingly if there are new entries.

Has anybody had an experience to integrate IBM Connections into his/her web page?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the Connections credentials for a user, you can call the activity stream REST API at:
/connections/opensocial/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all

Test it out on Greenhouse:
https://greenhouse.lotus.com/connections/opensocial/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all

Take a look at Bill Looby and Brian O'Gorman's presentation from IBM Connect 2013, particularly this slide:
http://www.slideshare.net/brianog/ad104-ibm-connections-actiivtystream-integration/43